# warning message on joomla login form

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

i have used joomla login form. but when i submit empty form it display error message only for password not for user name.login form code -

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php', true, $params->get('usesecure')); ?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="form-inline index-login">
    <?php if ($params->get('pretext')) : ?>
        <div class="pretext">
            <p><?php echo $params->get('pretext'); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>                       
                <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?>" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control"  placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (JPluginHelper::isEnabled('system', 'remember')) : ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input id="modlgn-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"/><?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME') ?>
                </label> 
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
            <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?>" />
            <?php else: ?>
            <label for="modlgn-passwd"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?></label>
            <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div>
                    <a class="forgot-password" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset'); ?>"><?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD'); ?></a></div>
            </div>
        <?php if (count($twofactormethods) > 1):?>
        <div id="form-login-secretkey" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-star hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY'); ?>">
                            </span>
                                <label for="modlgn-secretkey" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY'); ?>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-secretkey" type="text" name="secretkey" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?>" />
                        <span class="btn width-auto hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY_HELP'); ?>">
                            <span class="icon-help"></span>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <label for="modlgn-secretkey"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?></label>
                    <input id="modlgn-secretkey" type="text" name="secretkey" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?>" />
                    <span class="btn width-auto hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY_HELP'); ?>">
                        <span class="icon-help"></span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <button type="submit" tabindex="0" name="Submit" class="btn"><?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN') ?></button>
        <?php
            $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users'); ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return; ?>" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    <?php if ($params->get('posttext')) : ?>
        <div class="posttext">
            <p><?php echo $params->get('posttext'); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: i am using simple joomla login module on index page. i want simple empty username message but message display only for password

Comment: @PreetiBisht you have to debug the login module because by default it is not supplied the username empty warning!

Comment: Login module is ok, the problem is that login form validates password BEFORE username. The problem is with com_users login controller, you can ovveride it, or add a third party jquery validator for the login form.

Comment: Processing stops on the first detected error i.e. a required field no filled in.  If you want to override the string (in the language manager) so that it says that you have to supply both username and password you can, but I personally think that's somewhat insulting to users. It already indicates that both fields are required and how many users are so inexperienced with logging into sites on the web that they think they can do it without both a name and password?